# in regex how to match multiple Or conditions but exclude one condition

Tags: python, regex, python-re

If I need to match a string "a" with any combination of symbols @#$ before and after it, such as @a@, #a@, $a$ etc, but not a specific pattern @a$. How can I exclude this? Suppose there're too many combinations to manually spell out one-by-one. And it's not negative lookahead or behind cases as seen in other SO answers.

```
import re
pattern = "[#|@|&]a[#|@|&]"
string = "something#a&others"
re.findall(pattern, string)
```

Currently the pattern returns results like '#a&' as expected, but also wrongly return on the string to be excluded. The correct pattern should return [] on `re.findall(pattern,'@a$')`

Comment: What are all the symbols which you expect/accept here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the character class to list all the possible characters, and use a single negative lookbehind after the match to assert not `@a$` directly to the left.

Note that you don't need the `|` in the character class, as it would match a pipe char and is the same as `[#|@&]`

```
[#@&$]a[#@&$](?<!@a\$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C7Kqie/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tGlkcF)

```
import re

pattern = r"[#@&$]a[#@&$](?<!@a\$)"
print(re.findall(pattern,'something#a&others@a$'))
```

Output

```
['#a&']
```

Comment: nice solution. didn't know lookbehind can work with nothing after it @The fourth bird

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest a fairly ugly and complex regex pattern with lookarounds.  But instead, you could just proceed with your current pattern and then use a list comprehension to remove the false positive case:

```py
inp = "something#a&others @a$"
matches = re.findall(r'[@#&$]+a[@#&$]+', inp)
matches = [x for x in matches if x != '@a$']
print(matches)  # ['#a&']
```